# Bring data inside object in array along with other attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array as follows:

```
data = [
  {
    "data": {
        "id":1,
        "vol":"0.0"
        "details":{
            "ABC":"8.30",
            "OFG":"13.85",
            "SPG":"70.80"
        }
        
    }
  },
   {
    "data": {
        "id":2,
        "vol":"1.0"
        "details":{
            "ABC":"3.30",
            "OFG":"15.85",
            "SPG":"70.80"
        }
        
    }
  }
]
```

I want to make an arrays from above array such that data inside details object is every element comes outside. So in my final array there will not be details object. I just want to bring all attributes of details object with other object. So my final array will look something like this

```
data = [
{
    "data": {
        "id":1,
        "vol":"0.0"
        "ABC":"8.30",
        "OFG":"13.85",
        "SPG":"70.80"
        
    }
  },
   {
        "data": {
        "id":1,
        "vol":"0.0"
        "ABC":"8.30",
        "OFG":"13.85",
        "SPG":"70.80"
        
    }
  }
];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` with object destructuring.

```js
const arr=[{data:{id:1,vol:"0.0",details:{ABC:"8.30",OFG:"13.85",SPG:"70.80"}}},{data:{id:2,vol:"1.0",details:{ABC:"3.30",OFG:"15.85",SPG:"70.80"}}}];
let res = arr.map(({data: {details, ...rest}}) => ({data : {...rest, ...details}}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi If I want to do same thing with data. means getting all attributes out of data obj. how can I do that?

Comment: @Roma You mean like `let res = arr.map(({data: {details, ...rest}}) => ({...rest, ...details}));`?

Comment: @Roma Simply remove the `{ data:` and the corresponding `}` in the return. Please read the documentation: [Destructuring assignment](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [Object initializer](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Comment: {
  "id":1,
  "vol":"0.0"
  "ABC":"8.30",
     "OFG":"13.85",
     "SPG":"70.80"
  
  }

Comment: Means I want array elements without data and details object as I posted in my comment just above

Comment: how can I do that. Is it possible to update your code for this?

Comment: @Roma I already sent the code in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and do something like this:

```
const builtData = originalData.map(({ data }) => ({
  data: {
    id: data.id,
    vol: data.vol,
    ...data.details
  }
}))
```